# Excel IF(ISNUMBER(Search)) formula question to search for more than 3 keywords

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, excel-formula

Trying to understand why I get the error "too many arguments" when I do more than 3 of these as seen below:

Incorrect with Error:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AG$1,C1500)),$AG$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AH$1,C1500)),$AH$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AI$1,C1500)),$AI$1397)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AK$1,A1152)), AK1152))))
```

Correct:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AG$1,C1500)),$AG$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AH$1,C1500)),$AH$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AI$1,C1500)),$AI$1397)))
```

Can someone help with my syntax?

Comment: It might be helpful to know what your end goal is

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AG$1,C1500)),$AG$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AH$1,C1500)),$AH$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AI$1,C1500)),$AI$1397,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AK$1,A1152)), AK1152))))` You had two extra `))` before the final `IF`

Comment: `=INDEX($AG$1397:$AI$1397,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AG$1:$AI$1,C1500)),0))` depending on ones version may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shit-Enter.